# How to get contacts which are in the given list

Tags: java, android

My purpose is to set a list that comes from API which includes phonenumbers of the users of my app. So i only need to see contact that are in this list. But I dont know how set below code to do this. I mean in the below it opens contacts with all of the contact that are in the phone. I dont need to see the all the contacts but the ones that are in the given list

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,1);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode){
            case 1 :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                    Cursor cur = cr.query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {// thats mean some resutl has been found
                        if(cur.moveToNext()) {
                            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Log.e("Names", name);
                            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
                            {
                                // Query phone here. Covered next
                                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                                    String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                    Log.e("Number", phoneNumber);
                                }
                               phones.close();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    cur.close();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you are trying to get contacts which are common in API response and ContentResolver into some list ?

Comment: @rajan.kali exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you already have a `list` which has data from API, and create new list which will have common elements from `API list` and `ContentResolver`, now to add elements to your desired list, in `ContentResolver` check if the `PhoneNumber` is in API list before adding it to output.

```
ArrayList<String> apiPhoneNumbers;// this data is populated by API
ArrayList<String> commonPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
//inside onActivityResult
if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0){
  // Query phone here. Covered next
  Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
  while (phones.moveToNext()) {
      String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
      Log.e("Number", phoneNumber);
      if(apiPhoneNumbers.contains(phoneNumber)){//add to output only if it is in API list
          commonPhoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
      }
  }
  phones.close();
}
```

Comment: it is a post contact selection solution. What I need is, intent that opens contacts app will have only the numbers coming from api response. I couldn't find any solution so I don't know if that's possible. Thanks for the response mate